# Can we script and automate a browser, preferably with .Net?

Tags: .net, browser, automation, automated-tests

Is it possible to easily automate a browser, preferably with .Net?

I would prefer to automate Google Chrome, or a variant of it, but any browser would be welcome.

This would be used for automating tests or scraping web sites for data.

I was looking at [iMacro](http://www.iopus.com/iMacros/), but I would like to do it using .Net.

Any other hints/framework would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WebDriver project at http://seleniumhq.org/projects. They do also provide bindings for C#

Answer (score 3):

How about Selenium?

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

They have a C# version.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of automating browsers, usually `httpwebrequest`s ([check this out)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N) are used to fetch web pages with .NET. This will give you the complete response from the server and perform automatic redirection, manage cookies, etc. The only downside is that the page is not rendered. So you cannot actually "see" what the page actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Automating tests and scraping data are two different tasks. For automation I can heartily +1 the recommendations for WebDriver. I've used it a lot, it's a great tool, and I still do workshops and sessions on it regularly. You might also consider looking at [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/software-testing-tools.aspx) which does a great job of helping get through the many challenges around automated testing. (Disclaimer: I'm the evangelist for Test Studio...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://seleniumhq.org/ and also i suggest you take a look at: https://www.essentialobjects.com web site and use EO.WebBrowser.dll assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `WebBrowser` control (internet Explorer based) inside .Net Framework.